# Setting up simple relational database structure

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'd like to set up simple MySQL database but I'm a bit confused about everything, so let me try to explain...

I have 4 relevant tables, let's call them `POS`, `POS_STRUCT`, `POS_STRUCT_DIV` and `MEMBERS`.

Relation goes like this:
- `POS` can have many `POS_STRUCT` but a single `POS_STRUCT` can be associated to only one `POS`
- `POS_STRUCT` can have many `POS_STRUCT_DIV` but a single `POS_STRUCT_DIV` can be associated to only one `POS_STRUCT`
- `POS_STRUCT_DIV` can have many `MEMBERS` but a single `MEMBERS` can be associated to only one `POS_STRUCT_DIV`

My table `POS_STRUCT_DIV` will be consisted of few 'constants'. Let's call them `div_1`, `div_2` (...) `div_n`, and this is where my confusion starts.
Since this table will probably never change names or amount of those 'constants' should I even create a relation between `POS_STRUCT` and `POS_STRUCT_DIV`? Also, since records in `MEMBERS` will be sometimes associated to `POS_STRUCT_DIV` with a same name but on different `POS` and `POS_STRUCT`, should I create foreign keys for all 3 tables in `MEMBERS` table? What would be the most efficient way to solve this relation?

I tried to create an UML for this db, although I'm obviously not sure if it is correct at all...:

[image: UML diagram]

Comment: One paragraph says: *"a single MEMBERS can be associated to only **one** POS_STRUCT_DIV"*

Comment: And the other *"since many MEMBERS will be associated to POS_STRUCT_DIV with a same name but on **different** POS and POS_STRUCT"* This seems like a contradiction.

Comment: Ah sorry, I described this in a wrong way. Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you embed a list of `pos_div_name` in a column with type TEXT, you need to create table `POS_STRUCT_DIV` (POS_div in your diagram) as it has one-to-many relationship with `POS_STRUCT`.

You could use `pos_div_name` as the foreign key in the `MEMBER` as the name is never change. It saves you from looking up `pos_div_name` when loading `MEMBER` but the row size could be larger. So it is up to you.

Comment: OK, thanks for helping, I think I will set it up this way and just test the functionality in real world environment :) Since I will use Django, I think I will have all related data on disposition anyway.